# Django - Tastypie - How can I get query string parameters in my ModelResource Meta class?

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I have a **Django** application which I am writing an API for using **Tastypie**. I have an endpoint created which calls the code:

```
class CollectionModelResource(ModelResource):
    """API to retireve ObjInCollection for a specific collection
    """

    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = ObjInCollection.objects.filter(collection__collection='mycollection1')
        resource_name = 'objects'
```

This works well to return all those database records with `collection='mycollection1'`. However, I would like to pass this `mycollection1` value in via the querystring of the request. Yet I can't seem to find an exposed request object within this `Meta` class.

**Is there a way to get the `request` object from the `Meta` class inside a `ModelResource` of Tastypie???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tastypie does not allow this, but you can solve your problem in another way. You should create a custom `build_filters()` method which allows you to filter the queryset before processing a request see [docs][1].

Comment: Ah, `build_filters()` is a perfect solution. Thanks!